# Generating function of a random variable

Tags: generating-functions, random-variables, stochastic-analysis

I've got the following problem:

Give the generating function of the random variable $X$ whose mass function is defined by:
$$f(m) = P(X=m) = (m+1) p^2 (1-p)^m,$$ where $m$ is a positive integer (incl. $0$) and $0 < p < 1$.

How can I find this? And what's the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Generating function $$h(s)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}P(X=m)s^m=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)p^2(1-p)^ms^m$$ $$=\frac{p^2}{(1-p)s}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)((1-p)s)^{m+1}$$ $$=\frac{p^2}{(1-p)s}\frac{(1-p)s}{(1-(1-p)s)^2}=\frac{p^2}{(1-(1-p)s)^2}$$

$E[X]=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(X=m)$

On differentiating starting equation, $h'(s)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(X=m)s^{m-1}$

Thus, $h'(1)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(X=m)=E[X]$

$Var[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Now, $h''(1)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m(m-1)P(X=m)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m^2P(X=m)-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(X=m)$ $=E[X^2]-E[X]$

It implies $E[X^2]=h''(1)+E[X]=h''(1)+h'(1)$

and hence $Var[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=h''(1)+h'(1)-(h'(1))^2$

Comment: In fact, $m=0$ should be included and the result is $h(s)=p^2/(1-(1-p)s)^2$. Radius $R=1/(1-p)$.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot :) @Avatar and Did
one last question: if h(s) is the generating function, what would be the expectation E[X]?

Comment: @Did: I didn't notice that $m$(includes $0$) in the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnD: $E[X]=h'(1)$

Comment: @Avatar Please simplify the final formula for $h(s)$ (and you might want to avoid the decomposition of `m+1` into `m` + `1`).

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you two guys! Last question: The variance, defined as Var[X] = E((X-u)^2), where u is a positive measure, is in this case m, isn't it?